# JDK 17 maven clean install failed due to Java doclet

Tags: java, maven, java-17

I just updated my laptop's Java version to 17 and updated the maven POM file accordingly. However, I keep getting the following error when I ran `mvn clean install`:

```
Exit code: 1 - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/doclets/standard/Standard
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.loadDocletClass(Start.java:781)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.preprocess(Start.java:752)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.begin(Start.java:371)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.begin(Start.java:342)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Main.execute(Main.java:63)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Main.main(Main.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 16 more

Command line was: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc @options @packages
```

This is the configuration I used for the `maven-javadoc-plugin`:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-javadoc-json</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doclet>capital.scalable.restdocs.jsondoclet.ExtractDocumentationAsJsonDoclet</doclet>
                    <docletArtifact>
                        <groupId>capital.scalable</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-auto-restdocs-json-doclet-jdk9</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.11</version>
                    </docletArtifact>
                    <destDir>generated-javadoc-json</destDir>
                    <reportOutputDirectory>${basedir}${docDirectory}/report</reportOutputDirectory>
                    <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                    <show>package</show>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Does anyone know why it keeps trying to find the `com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard` even though I've specified another doclet to be used?

Comment: If you look at [Start.java:781](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+35/src/jdk.javadoc/share/classes/jdk/javadoc/internal/tool/Start.java#L781), you can see it's trying to load a class by name. So for some reason, the `doclet` config param looks like it's not being applied. I tried to trace it back, but it was a little complicated. I would run in debug and step through. Ultimately, all the config looks like it comes from here [Main.java:52](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17%2B35/src/jdk.javadoc/share/classes/jdk/javadoc/internal/tool/Main.java#L51), which is just a String[]

Comment: Never seen this notation: "*@options @packages*". Does it mean those are *literally* the arguments? If so, all your config is being lost. Or maybe those are some kind of shorthand in place of the actual arguments. Not sure

Comment: Do you use the latest version of the javadoc plug-in?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It's in the question. <version>3.4.0</version>

Comment: I would expect the following file: `target/apidocs/@options` which should tell which jars are used for doclets. It seems like one of those jars needs this class.

Comment: For Java 9+ support, use `spring-auto-restdocs-json-doclet-jdk9` as doclet dependency.

Comment: @Michael Latest version is 3.4.1 according to https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. The root cause of the issue is the doclet dependency, both 3.4.0 and 3.4.1 can work without any issues after I switched to the `spring-auto-restdocs-json-doclet-jdk9`.

Answer (score 1):

For Java 9+ support, use `spring-auto-restdocs-json-doclet-jdk9` as doclet dependency.

The implementation of `ExtractDocumentationAsJsonDoclet` extends from the deprecated class `Standard` , which was removed in JDK 17.